# How to find the image ID participating in the mosaicing in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, image-mosaic, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to find the image ID participating in the mosaicing, here is my mosaic process. Just the partial images appearing in the mosaicing result, not all those meet the filter conditions. The color difference of the whole image is too big, I want to match each image with histogram and then mosaic it, or maybe you have a better way?

```
var myimage = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
          .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-08-01').sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 
false).mosaic();                
var myimage1 = myimage.clip(dongbei);
var Viscolor= {
bands              :['B8','B4','B3'],
min                : 0.0,
max                : 10000.0,
};

Map.addLayer(myimage1, Viscolor, ' Color (843)');
```

"dongbei" is the shapefile I uploaded.[image: The whole image]